# How to avoid pressing same listview item twice in SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

I have a `Sliding Drawer` in my app and have fragments like `HomeFragment`,`FriendFragment` etc.Now the `HomeFragment` has a `map`.So when i am in `HomeFragment` i.e it is pressed and then if i click on the same button again it crashes.I had below code in my onCreateView()

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map_activity, null, false);
```

The errors in logcat is:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #46: Duplicate id 0x7f0a008a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.example.MAPit.MAPit.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:79)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

So i have a check in the `onCreateView` of `HomeFragment`

```
if (v != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
            if (parent != null){
               parent.removeView(v);
                }
        }
        try {
             v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_map_activity, null, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            //I have a toast check here and it's printing with vacant map and not crashing
        }
```

But giving this check it happened that app is not crashing but the map is not appearing in the `HomeFragment`.I debugged and saw that it is not inflating the layout i.e it is throwing `InflateException`.Then i tried to add this portion in my `HomeFragment` but again crashed.

```
 public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (map != null) {
            map = null;
        }
    }
```

I have tried to disable my that listview option but it didn't worked.what i tried is

```
if(listview.getChildAt(selectedPosition).isEnabled())
{
    listview.getChildAt(selectedPosition).setEnabled(false);
}
```

the error in logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.MAPit.MAPit.SlidingDrawerActivity.displayView(SlidingDrawerActivity.java:201)
            at com.example.MAPit.MAPit.SlidingDrawerActivity.onCreate(SlidingDrawerActivity.java:138)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
```

My listview onclick implementation code:

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Friend_Search_Fragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Groups_Fragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Friend_Request_Fragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                Bundle frienddata = new Bundle();
                frienddata.putString(Commands.Notification_job.getCommand(), Commands.Friends_Request.getCommand());
                fragment.setArguments(frienddata);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Friend_Request_Fragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                Bundle groupdata = new Bundle();
                groupdata.putString(Commands.Notification_job.getCommand(), Commands.Group_Join_Group.getCommand());
                fragment.setArguments(groupdata);
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new MyWallFragment();
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                break;
            case 6:
                Intent intent = new Intent(SlidingDrawerActivity.this,SignIn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        startFragment(fragment, position);
    }

    private void startFragment(Fragment fragment, int position) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();


            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            if (position != -1) {
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);

            }
            /*if(position == 0){
                if(mDrawerList.getChildAt(1)!=null)
                mDrawerList.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false);
            }*/
            //setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            //mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

I am out of idea how to prevent twice clicking on the same item in listview of slidingdrawer.Can anyone show me any path??Thanks in advance.

Comment: Empty catch blocks are strongly discouraged. It would help a lot if you posted the actual error message.

Comment: Actually it is not empty.I have a toast message printed there.ok.i am giving..

Comment: Post your listView onItemClick listener.

Comment: Your ListView's OnItemClickListener please.

Comment: yeah i have give that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    fm.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

you can try with adding above code before this 
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() line

Comment: thanks bro.Actually i thought that  getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); this is doing my job..